# How to copy pictures/photo to Ipad 1 with usb

Tags: photo, ipad

I am running `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`, and an `iPad 1 with IOS 4`.

My workplace has no Internet. Is there a way I can copy pictures (and possibly PDFs as well) to my iPad with usb?

I tried copying pictures directly into the `DCIM` folder, but that didn't work.

I searched `iTunes` for `PlayOnLinux`, but both `iTunes 10` and `iTunes 12` don't support syncing with `iDevices`

Is syncing the same as copying photos?

Thanks!

Comment: Apple uses an indexing system to know what photos it has. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way for Ubuntu to copy photos to an iOS device, unless it's jailbroken and has `afc2add` (iOS 7-) or `Apple File System "2"` (iOS 8+) installed from Cydia. Even then, it might not work.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution you can start FTP server on your ubuntu, install some ftp client on your IPad and connect to ubuntu from IPad through ftp.

Comment: oh shoot, i meant to ask how to do with non-wirelessly